# upload photos using multer node js via link

Tags: node.js, upload, multer

I am currently using the following code to upload a file by using `multer` (`is a node. js middleware for handling multipart/form-data`), but currently I am uploading files to the uploads folder in the js node project.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({

destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads')
},
filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    var id_photo = uuidv1();
    callback(null, id_photo + "-" + file.originalname);
}
})
```

Now I need to upload the file to folder ABC not upload to folder uploads, through the link provided
for example http://nanana.com/abc

ABC is the name of the folder where I want to fill the file

Answer (score 0):

you have to install first the fs-extra which will create folder here i am creating folder on bases of id in params you can do same like this

create seprate folder for multer like multerHelper.js

```
const multer = require('multer');
let fs = require('fs-extra');

let storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    let Id = req.params.id;
    let path = `tmp/daily_gasoline_report/${Id}`;
    fs.mkdirsSync(path);
    cb(null, path);
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    // console.log(file);

    let extArray = file.mimetype.split("/");
    let extension = extArray[extArray.length - 1];
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + "." + extension);
 }
})

let upload = multer({ storage: storage });

let createUserImage = upload.array('images', 100);

let multerHelper = {
    createUserImage,
}

module.exports = multerHelper;
```

in your routes import multerhelper file

```
const multerHelper = require("../helpers/multer_helper");

router.post(multerHelper , function(req, res, next) {

//Here accessing the body datas.

})
```